# C++ Template specialisation - illegal type for non-type template parameter '__formal

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I need to parse a custom protocol's frames that can contain intergers of various sizes (uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, etc...) and strings of chars prefixed by their length (uint16_t).

I want to write a template function to read such values from a vector of bytes to make the syntax more readable. Here are my functions :

```
template< typename type >
type read( const std::vector< byte > & bytes, uint index )
{
    if( index + sizeof( type ) > bytes.size() )
    {
        throw exception( "read() - Out of range." );
    }

    type val;
    memcpy( & val, & bytes[ index ], sizeof( type ) );

    return val;
}

template< std::string >
std::string read( const std::vector< byte > & bytes, uint index ) // ERROR HERE
{
    if( index + sizeof( type ) > bytes.size() )
    {
        throw exception( "read() - Out of range." );
    }

    uint16_t length = read< uint16_t >( bytes, 0 );

    std::string str( length, '\0' );

    for( uint16_t i = 0; i < length; ++i )
    {
        str[i] = read< char >( bytes, index + i );
    }

    return str;
}
```

I'm getting this error on VS2005 :

```
Error   1   error C2993: 'std::string' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '__formal'    c:\dev\floatinglicences\common\common.h 50
```

I'm not an expert with templates. It's the first time i need trying to do a template specialisation, so my syntax might be wrong.

Will you help me ? Thank you :)

Comment: Is one impolite when he deliberatly doesn't do something he should or when it simply doesn't come to his mind ?

Comment: I'd say so. It's the lack of thinking of your audience, and only thinking of your own problem. Maybe it's more "inconsiderate" than "impolite", though, take your pick. Anyway, lesson learned, and thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Okay anyway thanks for your help to everyone. I'll pick the fastest answer since they are all the same :)

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer from someone who's newer or has less reputation. I don't think any of the high-rep people have much use for  more, and it's an inspiration to the younger ones to get accepted.

Comment: @KerrekSB
Yep. I have another question if it's ok. WHat if i wanted to specialize my function to handle basic_string<T> instead of string ? :)

Comment: @Virus721: You cannot specialize function templates partially. Search this site, there are plenty of related questions and possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed from:

```
template< std::string >
std::string read( const std::vector< byte > & bytes, uint index )
```

to this:

```
template<>
std::string read< std::string >( const std::vector< byte > & bytes, uint index )
```

Answer (score 8):

A specialization looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(A x, B y, C z);                    // primary template

template <>
void foo<std::string> foo(A x, B y, C z);   // specialized for T = std::string
```

Answer (score 4):

The specialization should be:

```
template<>
std::string read< std::string >( blah blah blah)
```

Answer (score 3):

An explicit specialization looks like this:

```
template <>
std::string read<std::string>( const std::vector< byte > & bytes, uint index )
{
    // ...
}
```

Here the first `<>` is the set of template parameters.  There are none, since you're specifying an exact function type, not another template.  The second `<>` is the template arguments, specifying the template specialization being defined.

Note that the definition of an explicit specialization belongs in a source file, not a header file.  Unless you add `inline`.

Comment: Thanks for the note about inline!